# Failed to process package 'roscpp':

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I hope all of you are doing awesome.

I recently bought a raspberry pi 4 with just 1 GB of RAM
My raspberry is running Raspbian buster Lite.
I followed these instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source.
However when invoking catkin_make_isolated
I get the following error:

```
e::CallbackInfo&, const ros::CallbackQueue::CallbackInfo*>’ changed in GCC 7.1
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_deque.h:397:18: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘std::_Deque_iterator<ros::CallbackQueue::CallbackInfo, const ros::CallbackQueue::CallbackInfo&, const ros::CallbackQueue::CallbackInfo*>’ changed in GCC 7.1
[ 63%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/service_server_link.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/service_client.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/intraprocess_publisher_link.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/intraprocess_subscriber_link.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/node_handle.cpp.o
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/build.make:349: CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/intraprocess_publisher_link.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1072: CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'roscpp':
  Command '['/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp && /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

Any advice would be of huge help.

Thanks to you all in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351152/failed-to-process-package-%27roscpp%27:/) by [Lacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/54230/lacho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like raspberry is running out of memory when building the workspace:
Changed make parameter to -j2 and was able to solve it.

---

Originally posted by [Lacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/54230/lacho/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0